# Bidireccionalidad de datos entre EXCEL y SQL (profit)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

reciban un coordial saludo! tengo la siguiente interrogante.. en la empresa donde trabajo se usa el sistema de gestión profit. pero algunos informes de mecanizado (nos dedicamos a fabricar piezas mecánicas), es mas el seguimiento de las piezas se realiza por medio de excel, lo utilizamos para hacer cálculos, etc (tareas comunes en excel) pero para ello, se utiliza información que se "copia" a mano desde profit; se que Excel permite importar datos desde una base de datos SQL y lo muestra en una tabla... ahora mi pregunta ¿Existe bidireccionalidad en eso?; es decir, se que si se modifica algo del SQL se actualiza la tabla en excel pero al contrario funciona?? o como podría hacer eso?

Comment: Buen día, Si se pueden actualizar registros desde excel hacia sql, pero para ello vas a necesitar crear un macro VBA para poder realizar la conexión hacia la base de datos y editar, enviar o borrar registros desde Excel. Te recomiendo darte la vuelta por algunos tutoriales en youtube donde te expliquen más a detalle como realizar lo que te comento

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a el documento [ask], te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Puedes conectar perfectamente una base SQL a Excel y hacer lo mismo que harías en SQL. Si quieres traer datos, harías un SELECT. Si quieres actualizar/añadir datos, harías un INSERT INTO/UPDATE. Es totalmente bidireccional

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos! Tomaré nota y revisaré lo que me comentan!